# Html Action Link Not hiding when view page load in mvc

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor

I have html.Action link and i need to hide the link when page load depend on the some condition.That condition when bool value False it should hide else need to show..on the page...

```
        @{
        if (item.Approved)
        {
            @Html.ActionLink("Approve", "Approve", new { id = item.ClusterID }, new { @class = "btn btn-info" })*@
        }
        else
        {
            @Html.ActionLink("Approve", "Approved", new { id = item.ClusterID }, new { @style = "display:none" })
        }
    }
  }
```

the above code not working could you tell me what is wrong above code?

Comment: I see nothing wrong with your code maybe some css is overwriting `display:none`. Try with `new { @style = "display:none !important;"`.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe, you should write, `@if` missing:

```
 @if (item.Approved)
    {
        @*@Html.ActionLink("Approve", "Approve", new { id =item.ClusterID }, new { @class = "btn btn-info" })*@
    }
    else
    {
        @Html.ActionLink("Approve", "Approved", new { id = item.ClusterID }, new { @style = "display:none" })
    }
```

Comment: I wrote the code inside C# function using @{ If (item.Approved =true)} show the Link else not show i updated my code

Answer (score 0):

Please check your server side code first. If you are getting your bool value as expected or not. you are applying wrong condition. It should be.

```
@if(item.Approverd){@Html.ActionLink("Approve","Apporoved",new{@id=item.clusterID)}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you are getting value as false which will load below link

```
     @Html.ActionLink("Approve", "Approved", new { id = item.ClusterID }, new { @style = "display:none" })
```

i.e the else part

in that you are giving style attribute display:none  which will hide the else part even though its loaded.

check by removing the style attribute